# Wordpress basic functions show on top in custom shortcode

Tags: permalinks, shortcode

I created a function in my functions.php to show related posts for a custom posttype. Because the original developer used a themebuilder, I need to use a shortcode to display this function on the front-end.

A part of the code I use is

```
if($related_cats_post->have_posts()):
         while($related_cats_post->have_posts()): $related_cats_post->the_post();
            $postsList .= '<li><a href="' . the_permalink() . '">' .  the_title() . '</a></li>';
        endwhile;
    
        return '<ul>' . $postsList . '</ul>';
```

It gets the job almost done. The only problem is that because I use the_permalink() and the_title(), the link and the title shows up on top of the page and not in the unordered list as they supposed to do. I don't know why this happens and how to fix this. Is it maybe because I call the function within a shortcode?

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the equivalent functions that return their value. Those are [`get_the_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_pemalink/) and [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/).

Most WordPress template functions that begin with `the_` and echo their values have equivalent functions that return their values that begin with `get_the_`,

Comment: A thanks a LOT! Works perfect!